# Email folders inconsistence between webmail and IMAP on Exchange

Tags: email, thunderbird, exchange, webmail

My team uses Exchange 2010 as mail server.

I had some problems with Thunderbird and deleted my accounts data from it, and used the web interface for some time. I moved and renamed a lot of folders. Now I re-created my accounts, it accepts my login data and shows the old folder structure with the previous names.

After some experimenting it seems that if I move or rename a folder in Thunderbird, the web interface shows the change, but if I move or rename a folder in the web interface and then try to open it on Thunderbird, I get the following error message:

[image]

> The current operation did not succeed. The mail server for account
>   [name] responded: INBOX/[FOLDER] doesn't exist.

I can still open the inbox and I receive new emails just fine. I can use any folder on the webmail.

Comment: Someone with the same problem in 2009... http://superuser.com/questions/89543/can-i-configure-thunderbird-3-to-refresh-the-folder-list-for-an-exchange-imap-ac?rq=1

Comment: Have you tried to delete your Thunderbird profile.  It sounds like Thunderbird is still using the old cache problem which would be a problem with Thunderbird not Exchange.

Comment: @Ramhound Only a dozen times or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a fix for the issue. The following answer is meant for Thunderbird 17.0.6 in Ubuntu, but might work in other versions / OSes as well:

1. Unsubscribe from the offending folders where the error happens
2. Compress / condense your folders
3. Re-subscribe to your folders (you can press space to select all visible and marked folders)

[image]